# Not able to connect ganace to metamask

Tags: metamask, ganache, ganache-cli

Not able to connect metamask with ganache-gui. I tried two different app images :
ganache app image : ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64 and ganache-2.4.o-linux-x86_64 , neither seem to work .
With ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64 I was getting error *

> cannot connect to chain id please check rpc URL

- , with ganache-2.4.0-linux-x86_64 its unable to connect (never ending loader as shown in image ).

Same errors faced with ganache-cli

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.8.0-50-generic
Browser Brave

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling both ganache and metamask literally a thousand times .
Would be much grateful if someone is able to answer

[image]

[image]
[image]

Metmask network config :
[image]

Comment: Can u show the network config of „ganache“ in metamask?

Comment: Yess i ahve edited the post

Comment: Http: and not http. ?

Comment: I have tried everyting HTTP http https HTTPS

Comment: I mean in the picture you are using a "point" after http -> "http." it should be "double "point" -> "http:"